# How to access the ids of Different layout associated with different activity from another Activity and how to perfoem a onClick on it

Tags: android

i have different `fragments` in my application and they have different layout ,so i want to access the `layout ids` from a different activity for ex `button`,`textview` .

i have a `fragment`  called `MyFragment` and it has  a layout file `frag.xml` and a `MainActivity` with layout `main.xml`.in `frag.xml` i have

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/myButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

i want to access the id of `Button` of `farg.xml` in `MainActivity`
like `Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);`so how can i access it if i will acess like this it will throw a `NullPointerException`.also i want to perform the `onClick()` event for that button in `MainActivity`.

Comment: you just want to get the id?

Comment: yes and also perform onclick listener in MainActivity.

Comment: I don't know if you can perform click because I do not work with fragment, but I know the way to get the id, just give me a moment and I look back at my code and give you the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`R.id.myButton` is how you refer to the id of the button.  However, the button is only available in the view hierarchy of `frag.xml`.  So, `findViewById(R.id.myButton)` should return `null` if the button does not exist in the view hierarchy of the context under which you called `findViewById(R.id.myButton)`.

To access the button in the fragment from your main activity, you must write a method that the main activity can call on the fragment and then have the fragment do the work of accessing/modifying the button and returning whatever information you need to the main activity.

Comment: i am able to get the ids from by using the code   LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater(); 
          View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, pager);
          Button frg1Button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button01);
           but not able to perform onClickListener() in iy ,it s simple not triggering the listener.

Comment: You are missing the point.  When you do this you create a new instance of your fragment_1 view hierarchy.  The button you get when you call view.findViewById(R.id.myButton) is not the same button that gets created by your fragment nor is it the one that gets shown on the screen and receives touch events when you touch it.  That is a completely different button so setting an onClick listener on it dose not do anything unless you call frg1Button.performClick() or something.  My answer is correct, you just misunderstand what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the id of the button by

```
buttonid = getResources().getIdentifier(myButton , "Button", getPackageName());
```

The first parameter is the name from the XML after the @+id, the second is the type, the third is your package name.

Comment: how to perform the onClick event .

Answer (score 0):

Find main Layout of each fragment and store them in **static** array in a class.You can find your view in each fragment and store it in static field of a class(perhaps another class):

```
class Store{
public static view;
}
```

In fragment:

```
Stroe.view = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
```

In Activity:

```
Button btn = Store.view;
```

Comment: do you have any working example or its will be better to put a example becoz  i have tried with static its throwing null pointer exception.

Comment: @Abhijit Plase add snippet code.Also more details to your question.It is `Ambiguous`.

Comment: @Abhijit Please see my answer again.

Comment: You should avoid static classes.  They don't follow the same lifecycle as Activities and Fragments and their data (but not definitions) may be wiped by the Dalvik VM at its discretion (for example after the app has been idle for awhile the VM may remove the button causing `Store.view` to become null).

Comment: @hasan i cam able to access but not able to perfoem onClick event.

Comment: @Abhijit Do you set listener for it?And if yes,what do you want to do in onClick event?It may be depend on other fields on Fragment.

Comment: yes but its not working when i press the button its not firing any event.

Comment: @Abhijit What do you want to do in onClick event?It may be depend on other fields on Fragment.

Comment: i am just doing a simple toast.

Comment: @Abhijit Oh!! NO!! You inflate fragment layout in your Activity?!! So button that is in new inflated layout,has no listener.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27146/discussion-between-hasanghaforian-and-abhijit)